# How to proof the minimum number costed in a min-cut problem using s-t-cut?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Briefly the original question is to "solve a minimum-cut problem only use s-t cut, how many times it requires to find the minimum cut?"

And form [here](http://andrew-exercise.blogspot.com/2015/10/algorithms-design-and-analysis-part-1_51.html) I can see the answer is $n-1$ (where $n$ is the number of vertices):

> the solution is simple. Fix $s$ to be one of the vertex and $t$ varies
>   across all others, then we are done by picking the smallest one,
>   therefore we need at most $n−1$ call.

And my question is how to proof that? Why by fixing one vertex and going though the others can yield the correct answer?

About: This question is from a Coursera course's problem set, I passed that question mainly by luck. After that I searched the question and found the answer above. by instinct I thought $n-1$ is correct, but I don't know how to proof that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try and rephrase the [answer that you linked](http://andrew-exercise.blogspot.co.uk/2015/10/algorithms-design-and-analysis-part-1_51.html) in a way that's easier to understand.

**The Task**
 You need to need to find the minimum cut in the graph. That is, you need to partition the graph into two vertex classes (two parts), $U$ and $V$, such that the number of edges between $U$ and $V$ is as small as possible.

**What you are given**
A free 'oracle' that solves the *s-t minimum cut problem*.

How is this problem different from the original one? Here, the problem specifies two distinct vertices $s$ and $t$ that need to be in $U$ and $V$ respectively, that is, they can't be in the same vertex class. In the original problem, there is no such restriction, any partition of the graph will do.

So you are given an free function, say $F$ that can solve the *s-t minimum cut problem* for you.

**The question**
How many times do you need to call $F$ in order to solve the task?

**The answer**
Well, you can proceed as follows. Pick an arbitrary vertex and call that $s$. It must be part of some vertex class in the minimum cut partition, say $U$. Now, we don't know what lies in $V$ yet, so we try to set $t$ to each of the other vertices, and call $F$ on all such pairs of $(s, t)$. One of them must correspond to the minimum cut, as we are going through all possible cuts. We need to check this for each vertex $t$ as we can't be sure which vertices lie in $U$ until we have checked them all and found the minimum. Since there are $n$ vertices in total, we need to check $n-1$ other vertices for $t$.

So, $F$ is required to be called $n-1$ times.

Comment: Thank you! Now I can understand, I think I've focused too much on s-t cut and forgot that these two vertices belong to different partition groups.